# Python request to get altitude from a GeoJSON file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, geojson

I want to get the elevation of a segment (linestring) from a GeoJSON file.

I'm using this API:

- Documentation: https://api3.geo.admin.ch/services/sdiservices.html#profile
- request URL: https://api3.geo.admin.ch/rest/services/profile.csv

My problem is that I cannot get rid of an error saying the passed parameter 'geom' is not of GeoJSON type.

My geojson file:

```json
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "test",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Name": null, "description": "", "altitudeMode": "clampToGround", "tessellate": 1, "type": "linepolygon" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 7.349510580151255, 45.998132989830559 ], [ 7.346422156898689, 46.039529058312063 ], [ 7.287112064012824, 46.093617348068292 ], [ 7.236173542687846, 46.127135334945002 ] ] } }
]
}
```

My code:

```py
import requests
import json

api_url = "https://api3.geo.admin.ch/rest/services/profile.csv"
file_path = "geojson.GEOJSON"

with open(file_path) as f:
    geojson = json.load(f)
    r = requests.get(api_url, params=dict(geom=geojson))

print(r.json())
```

Output:

```json
{'error': {'code': 400, 'message': 'Invalid geom parameter, must be a GEOJSON'}, 'success': False}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import requests
import json

api_url = "https://api3.geo.admin.ch/rest/services/profile.csv"
file_path = "geojson.GEOJSON"

with open(file_path) as f:
    geojson, = json.load(f)['features']
    geom = json.dumps(geojson['geometry'])
    r = requests.get(api_url, params=dict(geom=geom))

print(r.content)
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/75325081/3) to the question [Python request to get altitude from a GeoJSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75325081/python-request-to-get-altitude-from-a-geojson-file) by the OP [axgibs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20166765/axgibs) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Look at the example in the docs. The API wants a single geometry, something like `{"type": "LineString", "coordinates": [[1,2], [3,4]]}`; you are giving it an entire FeatureCollection.

Comment: "coordinates" not "coords"

Comment: @elmiomar Oops, fixed, thanks! For some reason, I *always* make that mistake...